# writeLines() not producing a valid makefile

Tags: r, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to auto-generate a makefile using R, and have run into a very peculiar problem.

The makefile is produced using the following code:

```
v <- "histogram.tsv: histogram.r\r\tRscript histogram.r"
fileConn <- file("Makefile")
writeLines(v,  fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

This produces the following Makefile

```
histogram.tsv: histogram.r
    Rscript histogram.r
```

This Makefile doesn't build, but when I manually type in the Tab before "Rscript" it does! When I compare the text generated by write.lines to that generated by hand, `identical()` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Btw do you mean `writeLines(v,  fileConn)` instead of `writeLines(make,  fileConn)`? It makes more sense.

Comment: Whoops, I do, I'll edit

Comment: Wait, no I think the code is correct. I'm writing the vector `v`, to the fileconnection `Makefile`

Comment: I changed it. It was `writeLines(make, fileConn)` initially.

Comment: Could it be that the carriage return is creating the problem in `v`. Try replacing it with a line feed.

Comment: That works, Thanks! Do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: I'm glad it works. I have added this information in my answer, including a few more pieces of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine when I test it on Linux Mint. It's probable that your distribution is not forgiving when it comes to *carriage return* characters, typically used in windows. You can try removing the *carriage return* characters or use **dos2unix**:

> In DOS/Windows text files a line break, also known as newline, is a
>          combination of two characters: a Carriage Return (CR) followed by a
>          Line Feed (LF). In Unix text files a line break is a single character:
>          the Line Feed (LF). In Mac text files, prior to Mac OS X, a line break
>          was single Carriage Return (CR) character. Nowadays Mac OS uses Unix
>          style (LF) line breaks.

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
dos2unix Makefile
```

In your case, you'd also need to insert a newline character, hence set `v` as follows:

```
v <- "histogram.tsv: histogram.r\n\tRscript histogram.r"
```

**You can try a messier way of writing the makefile, in order to avoid such sort of problems:**

```
target: dependencies; \
command1; \
command2
```